# Pandas Rolling Mean Depending on Row Value

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframe in pandas:

```
Visitor    Home     Visitor_rtg    Home_rtg
 Sixers    Celtics     83.4         100.7
 Thunder   Warriors    97.7         105.6
 Bucks     Hornets     110.2        109.2
 Pelicans  Sixers      88.1         89.2
 Hornets   Wizards     90.1         102.3
```

What I would like to do is keep the rolling mean of rtg for each team, regardless of if they are home or visitor. So for example in the fourth row the sixers home_rtg would be `86.3` because `(83.4+89.2) / 2`. And the final row the Hornets would be `99.65` because `(109.2+90.1)/2` I have found `df.rolling()` but cant figure out how to get this to only calculate per team. The ordering also matters because I want to track the rating progression throughout the season.

Expected output:

```
Visitor    Home     Visitor_rtg    Home_rtg
 Sixers    Celtics     83.4         100.7
 Thunder   Warriors    97.7         105.6
 Bucks     Hornets     110.2        109.2
 Pelicans  Sixers      88.1         *86.3
 Hornets   Wizards     *99.65        102.3
```

Comment: Does the axis argument in `pandas.DataFrame.rolling` help? e.g. `df.rolling(axis=1)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### `stack`+`concat`+`groupby`+`mean`

IIUC, you can [`stack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) your dataframe, and [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html)+[`mean`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.mean.html) the values. No need for `rolling`

```
f = df[['Visitor', 'Home']].stack().reset_index(drop=True)
s = df[['Visitor_rtg', 'Home_rtg']].stack().reset_index(drop=True)
pd.concat([f, s], axis=1).groupby(0)[1].mean()
```

Outputs

```
Bucks       110.2
Celtics     100.7
Hornet      109.2
Pelicans     88.1
Sixers       86.3
Thunder      97.7
Warriors    105.6
Name: 1, dtype: float64
```

---

#### Edited answer

To get your desired output, you can use `expanding` (not rolling) to get the mean and `transform` to broadcast back to each original row. In the end, just `reshape` underlying values of your `dataframe` to get final output

```
df2 = pd.concat([f, s], axis=1)
df2[1] = df2.groupby(0).transform(lambda s: s.expanding().mean())
pd.DataFrame(df2.values.reshape(-1,4), columns=df.columns)


    Visitor     Home    Visitor_rtg Home_rtg
0   Sixers      83.4    Celtics     100.7
1   Thunder     97.7    Warriors    105.6
2   Bucks       110.2   Hornets     109.2
3   Pelicans    88.1    Sixers      86.3
4   Hornets     99.65   Wizards     102.3
```

Comment: This works to output each teams current average but I would like to place that number into the df at each game so that every game has that teams current average rating. My df is larger than the example above.

Comment: @GNMO11 Hm, I understand what you want now but have no idea how you want the information to be exposed in the dataframe. Mind posting expected output? (e.g. explaining how columns would be organized, etc)

Comment: Edited with expected output

Comment: this is great! Is it possible to extend to more columns than just `Visitor_rtg', 'Home_rtg`. I tried adding them into line 2 and then changing the reshape number in the last line to match the number of added columns but am getting an error of `Length mismatch`

Comment: @GNMO11 yes it is. Ideally, you'll have a third `.stack().reset_index()` structure, add this to concat, and re-adjust the shapes throughout the rest of the code

Answer (score 0):

A not particularly pleasant solution:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([['Sixers', 'Celtics', 83.4, 100.7], 
                   ['Pelicans', 'Sixers', 88.1, 89.2]], 
                  columns=['Visitor', 'Home', 'Visitor_rtg', 'Home_rtg'])
melted = df.melt(['Visitor', 'Home'])
pd.concat([melted.loc[melted['variable'] == 'Visitor_rtg', ['Visitor', 'value']].rename(columns={'Visitor': 'Team'}), 
            melted.loc[melted['variable'] == 'Home_rtg', ['Home', 'value']].rename(columns={'Home': 'Team'})], 
           axis=0, 
           ignore_index=True
      ).groupby('Team').mean()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `reshape` on the underlying `numpy` arrays for an efficient solution.

---

***Step 1***
There is quite a bit of reshaping involved, and finally putting the data into an `empty` numpy array.

```
home = df.iloc[:, [1,3]]
away = df.iloc[:, [0,2]]
total = np.empty((home.shape[0] * 2, home.shape[1]), dtype=object)
total[::2] = away
total[1::2] = home
```

***Step 2***
Now that we have the data formatted, we can use `expanding.mean` and a bit more reshaping

```
d = pd.DataFrame({'team': total[:, 0], 'score': total[:, 1].astype(float)}) 
out = d.groupby('team').score.expanding().mean().reset_index().sort_values(by='level_1') 

pd.DataFrame(
    out[['team', 'score']].values.reshape(-1, 4)[:, [0,2,1,3]],
    columns=df.columns
)
```

```
    Visitor      Home Visitor_rtg Home_rtg
0    Sixers   Celtics        83.4    100.7
1   Thunder  Warriors        97.7    105.6
2     Bucks   Hornets       110.2    109.2
3  Pelicans    Sixers        88.1     86.3
4   Hornets   Wizards       99.65    102.3
```